# Procedure updating table with CLOB data type column does not work properly

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql

I have a table with below structure:

```
create table bb_analysisitems_batch
( batch_id                number,
  batch_name              varchar2(100),
  batch_result            clob )
```

There are other columns in the table I just wanted to simplify it. I have a procedure too for updating the table's data, here is the code of the procedure :

```
procedure update_bb_analysisitems_batch(v_batch_result in bb_analysisitems_batch.batch_result%type,
                                        v_batch_id     in bb_analysisitems_batch.batch_id%type,
                                        v_batch_name   in bb_analysisitems_batch.batch_name%type) is

  -- P.tourang
  -- 10/2/2022

begin

  update bb_analysisitems_batch t
     set t.batch_name     = v_batch_name,
         t.batch_result   = v_batch_result 
   where t.batch_id       = v_batch_id;    
  commit;

end;
```

The problem is that when I test the procedure with the below input parameters :

```
   v_batch_result = 'ddddddddd'
   v_batch_id     = 12
   v_batch_name   = 'hello'
```

the procedure does not fail, and the `batch_name` column gets updated to the new value which is 'hello' , however, the `batch_result` column that has `clob datatype` does not get the new value! what do you think the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could not reproduce, works fine for me. Post actual steps and output.

Comment: Unrelated, but do not commit inside a stored procedure.